# Solving $\sin5x \cos3x = \sin6x \cos2x$ two ways gives different solutions. Which approach is correct?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

The question is:

> $$\sin5x \cos3x = \sin6x \cos2x$$

I had two approaches:

1. $$\sin5x \cos3x = \sin6x \cos2x \\
      2\sin5x \cos3x = 2\sin6x \cos2x \\
      \sin8x+\sin2x=\sin8x+\sin4x \\
      \sin2x=\sin4x \\ \sin4x-\sin2x=0 \\
    2\sin x\cos3x=0  \\
   \implies \sin x=0 \\ x=n\pi
   \implies  \cos3x=0 \\ 3x={(2n+1)\pi}/2 \\
   x={(2n+1)\pi}/6$$

These were the solutions in the first approach.

2. $$\sin5x \cos3x = \sin6x \cos2x \\
      2\sin5x \cos3x=2\sin6x\cos2x \\
      \sin8x+\sin2x=\sin8x+\sin4x \\
      \sin2x=\sin4x\\ \sin4x-\sin2x=0 \\
      2\sin2x.\cos2x-\sin2x=0 \\
   \sin2x(2\cos2x-1)=0 \\
   \implies \sin2x=0 \\
   x=n(π/2)\\
   \implies 2\cos2x-1=0 \\
   \cos2x=1/2 \\
   2x=2n\pi\pm(\pi/3) \\
   x=n\pi\pm(\pi/6)$$

These were my solutions in the second approach. This was also the approach given in the textbook for this question.

My question is:

> Why do these solutions not match in the two cases? Have I made any mistake in the first approach?

Comment: This is difficult to read. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What makes you say that they are different ?

Comment: I now understand that they are indeed equivalent. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solutions are equivalent, indeed for $x\in [0,2\pi)$

- $x=n\pi \land x={(2n+1)\pi}/6 \implies x\in\{0,\frac \pi 6,\frac \pi 2,\frac 2 3 \pi,\pi,\frac 4 3 \pi,\frac 32\pi,\frac {11}6\pi\}$
- $x=n\frac \pi 2 \land x=n\pi\pm(\pi/6) \implies x\in\{0,\frac \pi 6,\frac \pi 2,\frac 2 3 \pi,\pi,\frac 4 3 \pi,\frac 32\pi,\frac {11}6\pi\}$

As an alternative by [product to sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) we have that

$$\sin(5x)\cos(3x)=\frac12\sin(8x)+\frac12\sin(2x)$$

$$\sin(6x)\cos(2x)=\frac12\sin(8x)+\frac12\sin(4x)$$

then

$$\sin(5x)\cos(3x)=\sin(6x)\cos(2x) \iff \sin(2x)=\sin(4x)$$

and use that

$$\sin A=\sin B \iff A=B+2k\pi \lor A=\pi - B+2k\pi$$

that is

$$x=k\pi \lor x=\frac \pi 6+k\frac \pi 3$$

which are equivalent to both your solutions.

Comment: I now understand that they are indeed equivalent. In objective questions, they'll give us any one of these solutions that we achieved in the two cases. In that case I'll have to check which one gives me the same answers in any range, say [0,2π], am I correct?

Comment: @Starsandgalaxies Yes solutions are periodic.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score 3):

The two solutions are equivalent - they both include all numbers which are congruent to $0$, $\pi/6$, $\pi/2$ or $5\pi/6$ mod $\pi$. It is just that in your first solution you have divided into the first case and a combination of all others, whereas your other solution groups alternate cases together.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$.

$$(z^5-z^{-5})(z^3+z^{-3})=(z^6-z^{-6})(z^2+z^{-2})$$

expands as

$$z^2-z^{-2}=z^4-z^{-4}$$ or $$\sin2\theta=\sin 4\theta=2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta.$$

Hence you have the roots of $\sin2\theta$, $\dfrac{k\pi}2$, and the solutions of $\cos2\theta=\dfrac12$, $\pm\dfrac\pi6+k\pi$.

In terms of multiples of $\dfrac\pi6$,

$$0,3,5,6,7,9,11,12,13,15,17,18,19,21,23,24,25,\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

**Case**$\#1:$ $$\dfrac{m\pi}2=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}6$$
$$\iff2n+1=3m\iff2(n-1)=3(m+1)\iff3|(n-1)\iff n\equiv1\pmod3$$

**Case**$\#2:$
$$\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}6=m\pi\pm\dfrac\pi6=\dfrac{\pi(6m\pm1)}6\iff2n+1=6m\pm1$$

For $'+',$  $$2n+1=6m+1\iff n=3m, n\equiv0\pmod3$$
For $'-',$  $$2n+1=6m-1\iff n=3m-1, n\equiv-1\pmod3$$

So, all three possible values of $n$ are covered.